# string is not allowed to have letters

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

I found this kind of script here but it's not working , why ?

```
while true
do
    echo "which number ?"
    read number
    if [[ $number =~ ^[A-Za-z_]+$ ]]; then
        echo "no letters!"
   else
        break
    fi
done
echo "good!"
```

I get the following :

```
./A.sh: 7: ./A.sh: [[: not found
```

thanks for help !

Comment: The first line of the script is probably `#!/bin/sh`, but `[[` is Bash feature. Change the first line to `#!/usr/bin/env bash`

Comment: @janos The shebang shouldn't be used to try to enforce some sense of portability. The script might be written for a specific version (or at least specific minimum version) of `bash`, and you have no idea if the users's `PATH` will result in the correct version of `bash` being used. Shebangs should be considered a *local* convenience only, unless you are targeting a published standard like `/bin/sh`.

Comment: @chepner I'm not sure if I got you correctly. Can you elaborate on that *local convenience* part?

Comment: The shebang only specifies a *path*; you as the script writer have no way of knowing what is actually installed at that location unless it is a machine under your control. As a real example, `/bin/bash` on a Linux machine is typically much different (read: newer) than `/bin/bash` on a Mac OS X. However, the POSIX standard specifies very specifically what `/bin/sh` needs to refer to, so you could safely use that as a portable shebang. Otherwise, the shebang is nothing more than a rough hint as to what the script should be executed with.

Comment: Python's distribution tools take an interesting approach. The script writer simply uses `#!python` as a placeholder. The installation process uses the *installer's* local configuration to replace that with a path to a Python interpreter on the target machine.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! You are right, and for portability reasons I would not use bash for anything that does not run on my machine only. Anyhow, using `#!/bin/bash` will likely solve the OP's problem.